# How to pass value from rest service to camel route?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have exposed as service as below

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
    rest("/batchFile").consumes("application/json").post("/routeStart").type(BatchFileRouteConfig.class).to("startRouteProcessor");
```

Based upon the request from rest service,i would start camel route in processor as below

```
@Component("startRouteProcessor")
public class StartRouteProcessor implements Processor {


    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        BatchFileRouteConfig config = exchange.getIn().getBody(BatchFileRouteConfig.class);
        String routeId = config.getRouteId();
        String sourceLocation = config.getSourceLocation();
        exchange.getContext().startRoute(routeId);
    }
}
```

I need to pass the sourceLocation from above bean to below route

```
@Component
public class FileReaderRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:sourceLocation")
       .log("File Reader Route route started");
    }

}
```

Above is sample code..request you to help me in passing the **sourcelocation** from **StartRouteProcessor**  to **FileReaderRoute**

Comment: check [part 2 of this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48557782/3759505), this will work for Spring, but not sure for spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, since in your example is `FileReaderRoute` already started at the time of calling `batchFile` endpoint.

You can do it in slightly different way.

Extract your `FileReaderRoute` to `direct`. Something like:

```
@Component
public class FileReaderRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:fileReaderCommon")
       .log("File Reader Route route started");
    }
}
```

And then you can create new route at runtime:

```
@Component("startRouteProcessor")
public class StartRouteProcessor implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        BatchFileRouteConfig config = exchange.getIn().getBody(BatchFileRouteConfig.class);

        exchange.getContext().addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:"+config.getSourceLocation())
                    .routeId(config.getRouteId())
                    .to("direct:fileReaderCommon");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Do not forget to take sufficient sanitizing of input, since you are allowing user to create file consumer based on user input. In your approach, there is a high risk of path traversal attack.