# pollEnrich with dynamic URI and its number of executions

Tags: apache-camel

I want to listen on ActiveMQ topic based on the hostname of system and some other logic. I planned to use `pollEnrich` for it so I evaluate my logic and provide topic name in `pollEnrich` but [as per document](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-enricher.html):

> `pollEnrich` or `enrich` does **not** access any data from the current Exchange which means when polling it cannot use any of the existing headers you may have set on the Exchange. For example you cannot set a filename in the `Exchange.FILE_NAME` header and use `pollEnrich` to consume only that file. For that you **must** set the filename in the endpoint URI.

How i can figure out this

```
from("timer://ipc?repeatCount=1")
.. some logic..
.setHeader("topic_no",simple("{{env:HOSTNAME}}"))
.pollEnrich("mqtt:foo?host=tcp://0.0.0.0:1883&subscribeTopicNames=${header.topic_no}/status&clientId=ipc")
.to("log:my?showAll=true&multiline=true");
```

Please don't suggest to use hostname directly in URI. As I highlighted I have to compute other logic too.

- What other option or way I can use?
- Will pollEnrich kept listening on topic or it will listen once and end the route?

**Update1:**
I figured out we can use simple expression with for dynamic URI, But one issue with pollEnrich it only pick one message how i can make sure it kept on listening as consumer? I want that before pollEnrich part get execute once and TopicListener kept listening till application is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will pollEnrich kept listening on topic or it will listen once and end the route?

Same as the fact you have figure out, Camel `pollEnrich` component will listen on topic and consume at most one message per call.

> What other option or way I can use?

1. Repeat `pollEnrich` by `loop`
2. Create new route at run-time by `routeBuilder`

Option 1 is naive, but simple in concept. `pollEnrich` will do once and `loop` will repeat it. However, this method need to handle more scenario than you might expected.

Option 2 is a better approach. You create a route at run-time and the consumer endpoint URI is pass by variable. That said, you can create the consumer route dynamically after your computation logic.

[Example for routeBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48557782/3759505)

Comment: so just a doubt, if we are using two 'from', then camel will be listening to both right?